# HTML Structure inside Lists - Jquery Mobile 1.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am upgrading from Jquery Mobile Alpha 3 to 1.0 stable.

I'm trying to use the following HTML structure in my lists, it was allowed in a3, but now it is not rendering the entire contents of the list item as a link (it did previously):

```
<li>
<h3><a href="#">This is an anchor inside a h3</a></h3>
<p>Paragraph text</p>
</li>
```

Old version (desired result): http://jsfiddle.net/dinie/CWmdf/

Using JQM 1.0 : http://jsfiddle.net/dinie/QRB4P/

I am required to preserve this HTML structure, is there a way to solve this problem by editing/extending the Jquery Mobile plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be the best you can do without overriding the CSS

- http://jsfiddle.net/QRB4P/2/

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-formatting.html

Comment: Doesn't putting a <h3> inside an <a> make the HTML invalid? Wonder why JQM encourages this

Comment: @umami not sure since this is HTML5 or if that even makes a difference. Head over to http://validator.w3.org/ and check

Answer (score 0):

You should include everything inside the A tag, like this:

```
<li>
 <a href="#">
   <h3>This is an anchor inside a h3</h3>
   <p>Paragraph text</p>
 </a>
</li>
```